# BULK INSERT from datafile causes error on datetime type

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

I have a data file that contains a datetime field in (yyyy mm dd) format. 
I have created a bcp format file to import the data but when run the statement, I get an error
**Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 16 (ReleaseDate).**

How can I tell the bcp utility to treat the field in (yyyy mm dd) format or convert the format to that sql server expect ?

Comment: import it into a varchar column and then do the string manipulations inside sql server will save you a lot hassle.

Comment: I have did that before and it works. It works for decimal(8,3) type but not for 'bigint' types. I just was wondering whether there is a straight forward way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two comments on the problem.

**First**, make sure you are using a ASCII code page, not UNICODE which is two bytes.

**Second**, if BCP is having issues you can play around with the format file.

If that does not work, change from ETL to Extract Load Translate (ELT).

Bulk load from file to a varchar() column in a table.  Translate with a stored procedure to the right data type.

Comment: `BULK load from file to VARCHAR()`; this usually does the trick because it allows even bad values and gives you the chance to clear bad data before a final input into the final destination.

Comment: I rather use SSIS since I can direct bad rows to a hospital table for later processing or review.  Just my preference.  But I have done both in the past.